# Get last available date for certain category

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

I have a table (Table1) in Power Pivot which consists of values with dates and category assigned to them (non-unique):

```
CAT      DATE         VALUE
A        2015-01-03   12
A        2015-01-07   2
B        2015-03-14   50
```

Then, in another table I have the same categories with dates:

```
CAT      DATE         
A        2015-01-04   
A        2015-01-06   
A        2015-01-08   
B        2015-03-16
```

In Table2 I want to get value from Table1 corresponding to latest date lower or equal than date from Table2 in current row for that category, i.e.:

```
CAT      DATE         VALUE_FROM_TABLE_1
A        2015-01-04   12 (value from 2015-01-03)
A        2015-01-06   12 (value from 2015-01-03)
A        2015-01-08   2  (value from 2015-01-07)
B        2015-03-16   50 (value from 2015-03-14)
```

Alternatively, I need a formula for Table2 to calculate latest date from Table1 which is lower or equal to this from Table2 for category in the current row, like this:

```
CAT      DATE         LAST_AVAILABLE_LOWER_OR_EQUAL_DATE_FOR_CAT
A        2015-01-04   2015-01-03
A        2015-01-06   2015-01-03
A        2015-01-08   2015-01-07
B        2015-03-16   2015-03-14
```

I have tried various combinations of LASTDATE and CALCULATE but to no avail.
I will be grateful for any hint.

Comment: Self-reply, it is:

`=CALCULATE (
    Lastdate( Table2[DATE] );
    FILTER (
        ALL (Table2);
        Table2[DATE] <=[DATE] && Table2[CAT]=[CAT]
    )
)`

Comment: If that is the answer, can you add it as an actual answer (down below) and then accept it?  This helps those of us looking for unanswered questions to help.

Comment: Sure, I have added the answer and I will accept it tomorrow. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out, and it goes like this:

```
=CALCULATE ( 
    LASTDATE( Table2[DATE] ); 
    FILTER ( 
        ALL (Table2); 
        Table2[DATE] <=[DATE] && Table2[CAT]=[CAT] 
    )
 )
```